# How to create a type containing only the common properties from a type union?

Tags: typescript

I want to map over union of arrays, how can I make it type safely?

I have a solution, but I want to avoid hard-coding the types from the type union.
When calculating `newArr1`, as expected, I get an error: `Property 'field2' does not exist on type 'Common<A, B>'`
Is there a way to get the same error when calculating `newArr2`?

([link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+TYCAGwBMBGALmQGcwpQBzHPA4kgJipAFcBbAI2hYAvllCRYiFACFMzXK1KUadRiKxYwATwAOKAMIB7Xr0MgAPKgA0yaQD5kAXjl5kAbQAKyUMgDWELUMYNGQAMj8AoNsAXSpUT2jkAB9bBIBudSwYbhAEMGAzZF44HVQoKDgtAAo4cri3RJTpBoBKOXlkBDNaZBAIAHcyqDInZBry5DhqZCMTM0sbe1aAOmKdKuAnB2BlxQ42gHoDyemIAA89PIgSG2goQygqD3u9KG1kAHI99g-kEkMINMQIYwMhzsAeoVtHpPrNTBZrLY7B8NK4jsgABaGfqdOAgZAASWQDAgoLAGJQ1DgvBQdweyH6wHJhm4oIxtRIAFouiRGMhyShoYD8PdePyKfzdCgcgUQAB+DpdEA9PqDcrsUbjKAnZAAWTgDGACAAogA3CDgbhwIhELQAMVFACkENaAF7mIVRWpQOwtVYlDZbby7QikdgtVF4KCk7hQfGqoZkTJAA))

```js
interface A {
    field1: string
    field2: number
}
interface B {
    field1: string
}

type Common<A, B> = {
    [P in keyof A & keyof B]: A[P] | B[P];
}

function mapArray(arr: A[] | B[]) {

    const newArr1 = (arr as Common<A, B>[]).map(i => i.field2) // error

    // how can I get the same error without hard-coding the types from the type union?
    const newArr2 = (arr as MagicEventuallyFromJcalz<typeof arr>).map(i => i.field2)

    return newArr1
}
```

Comment: Unions kind of act this way already.  The problem that unions of functions are hard to call.  Do you have some use case better than `mapArray()`?  Because I'd just use `arr as (A|B)[]` here without doing type craziness.

Comment: Also, wouldn't the second one be something like `(arr as Common<typeof arr[number]>[])`?  Or do you expect `Common<A[] | B[]>` to somehow be the same as `Common<A | B>[]`?  Undistributing "arrayness" seems hard to get for free; it could be hardcoded, but I guess I'd like to see a more full use case

Comment: And my first draft of `Common<T>` without arrayness stuff would be `type Common<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>`.

Comment: Why not `mapArray(arr: (A | B)[])`? `mapArray(arr: A[] | B[])` is saysing you either have an array of all A or all B,  its the union of array types not of the types of items the array's have so it would be difficult w/o having 2 code paths for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks jcalz and William Lohan!

A real use case: for 2 different requests from an external api, I get 2 different responses:

1. an array with users having many details about each user, and
2. an array with users having a small subset of the details from the previous point

Using the same function which parses either one of the 2 array from above, I want to get the users' ids (`id` is a common property of users from both arrays), 1) in a type safe manner and 2) without hard-coding the array types in function body. Based on your comments jcalz, I was able to achive that. You deserve the credit for the solution, if you post an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

The solution I found ([link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCITHYAbCATAVQGdpkBvAKGWuWDwC5kQBXAWwCNoqbW4QBPRiw5cayAPZgAFtEZEwUUAHNu1GMAjY8RRu3HjcfCgF8KoSLEQoAwuNYAHRGGKlKYukLacoJihTD89jZ2rOIgADwAKgB8yAC8yAAKwAgA1lEANMipEPziMMgxfgFByAQgjmn4AGJQdgCCUFBw-FGxCZHIEAAekCDayAAUoDCkBACUANoAusgA-GXIQhAAblwUMMwgCGDAYchKGC5QAJLatQ32wIPMJFBEAFJEYRes9VeM6Jg4+MczyAAfZC2BxOP7TcbkPxiAD0MOQAHdxFBUkRkHA0T0gjt8IxQMg9NJkNhQBA0ZxsOIEVk4MgwJimsjaGjmsASHhEcBpOJmGBkFI4FA8ABaBDiPDKOkyOmBMnIGB1VhSlBbPYgGVBaE0MUgeTIW7QM5EACM8SGBvuTxeivewHRaJBoQi5UqOTwr0azVaJQg+X1d0ezxAHqu0WiM3GADpePZhvFYsBI5IZFBxlrqDq9RajQAmM03ANW4M2q724EhMLhH1+i2B62XYCTYTeabhiHRuCxu1xBNJ6TQNOqZBQDDMKDq7PaY2+ChAA)):

```js
interface DetailedUser {
    id: number
    many: number
    other: string
    fields: boolean
}
interface CompactUser {
    id: number
}

type Common<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>

type UnpackedFromArray<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : never

function getUserIdsFromApi(usersJsonFromApi: DetailedUser[] | CompactUser[]) {

    // works as expected: in both lines below, a ts error is raised
    // note that the types (DetailedUser[], CompactUser[]) are not hard-coded, but determined from variable usersJsonFromApi

    const userIds1 = (usersJsonFromApi as Common<UnpackedFromArray<typeof usersJsonFromApi>>[]).map(i => i.other)

    const userIds2 = (usersJsonFromApi as Common<typeof usersJsonFromApi[number]>[]).map(i => i.other)

    return userIds1
}
```

Comment: I generally prefer `type UnpackedFromArray<T extends Array<any>> = T[number]` (not that you need to give it a name for such a short thing) to the conditional type `T extends (infer U)[] ? U : never` since the former, a lookup type, is easier for the compiler to reason about.  But they both work.