# Typescript: Implement Union Type

Tags: typescript

I know that implementing Union Types is not possible in TS, what is absolutely reasonable. But I'm probably looking for something similar / else:

```
type TypeA = { a: string, b?: string }
type TypeB = { a: string, c?: string }
type UnionType = TypeA | TypeB;
type IntersectionType = TypeA & TypeB;

// Error:
// A class can only implement an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.(2422)
class UnionClass implements UnionType {
    checkUnionProperties() {
        let x: UnionType = { a: '' };
    }

    a = 'a';
}

//This is possible
class IntersectClass implements IntersectionType {
    checkUnionProperties() {
        let x: IntersectionType = { a: '' };
    }

    a = 'a';
}
```

I'd like to be able to implement a Type / Interface, that has all the properties the Types have **in common** (in this case only `a: string`), but not really a class that is of TypeA or TypeB. Is there a language-feature I'm looking for?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56366737/157247

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript how to create type with common properties of two types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375916/typescript-how-to-create-type-with-common-properties-of-two-types)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56366737/how-to-create-a-type-containing-only-the-common-properties-from-a-type-union#comment99336924_56366737), [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) points to the fact that `Pick<T, keyof T>` when `T` is a union type provides a type which only has the common parts:

```typescript
type TypeA = { a: string; b?: string; };
type TypeB = { a: string; c?: string; };
type UnionType = TypeA | TypeB;

type Common<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>;

type X = Common<UnionType>;
//   ^? − type X = { a: string; }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8oEMBcUDOwATgJYB2A5gNxQBGA-LgSRdQL6UBQoks8AQinRZGRMlSgBjBvlEso7LvCgBVUsQD2pOD1TbEUAD69IfTop4BhdQFtrmgDwwAfIIAKxCQGtHAGiieIEHUAM1gnM25oAA1BK1sHVQ0teHCOAHo0qCyAPTooQCQiKEioGNQMHBlmcVYOIA). *(For the avoidance of doubt, [it's true](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8oEMBcUDOwATgJYB2A5gNxQBGuBJF1AvtQPRtQCymAJtAAMaArKV5QBAYwEA6OQChQkWPABCKdFnpEyVKJO2M9rKByhyZpAPakAtFbDBiNzABtF8KAFVSz0nGVUAMQoAB8VSFVKeQ9lAGErAFtEmwAeGAA+DQAFYkkAa3SAGih8iBArADNYDOjY6AANDQTktJ8-YNr5MygoAD0AfnkgA) even when the other properties — `b` and `c` in your example — aren't optional.)*

You can `implement` the result:

```typescript
type TypeA = { a: string; b?: string; };
type TypeB = { a: string; c?: string; };
type UnionType = TypeA | TypeB;

type Common<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>;

class UnionClass implements Common<UnionType> {
    checkUnionProperties() {
        let x: UnionType = { a: '' };
        console.log(x);
    }

    a = "a";
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8oEMBcUDOwATgJYB2A5gNxQBGA-LgSRdQL6UBQoks8AQinRZGRMlSgBjBvlEso7LvCgBVUsQD2pOD1TbEUAD69IfTop4BhdQFtrmgDwwAfIIAKxCQGtHAGiieIEHUAM1gnMwkAG0w8PBU1TQto2KhiazBIiGsIUmA4q1sHVQ0teBc0DigqyQALCC9izVdCdUhCYGIIPAAKAEp0SuqhzOAoAA9cRtKdIRwoAHJ5+U4hoYlNPHVMgDpI9XJusd6V6tYOQarMQQAiTGvOViA)

[Here's an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8oEMBcUDOwATgJYB2A5gNxQBGA-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) without `a = "a";` in the class, so the class doesn't implement the interface correctly — and it is indeed an error as you'd hope.

---

User [makeitmorehuman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142191/makeitmorehuman) points to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375916/typescript-how-to-create-type-with-common-properties-of-two-types) in a comment, which has [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68416189/157247) from [qiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12548458/qiu) that handles it differently if `TypeA` and `TypeB` both have a property with the same name but *different types*. For instance, if you had `x: string` in `TypeA` but `x: number` in `TypeB`, the `Common<TypeA | TypeB>` above would result in a type with `x: string | number`. That may be what you want, but if not, [qiu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68416189/157247) answer has you covered with the `SharedProperties` type (see the answer for details), which would leave `x` out entirely:

```typescript
// `OmitNever` and `SharedProperties` from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68416189/157247
type OmitNever<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K];
};
type SharedProperties<A, B> = OmitNever<Pick<A & B, keyof A & keyof B>>;
```

Your `class` could use that, like this:

```
class UnionClass implements SharedProperties<TypeA, TypeB> {
    checkUnionProperties() {
        let x: UnionType = { a: "" };
        console.log(x);
    }

    a = "a";
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAMHkFsEsBcByBTAbsgTuUBDAdgCYQDKAFjhsgQAoYD2ADpvLMgM7YBm90AXKKXjwGbXiDbwcAYwDWddBk4AbOgHcAdFLrRgOYADYAHABYAjPtOGAnMFMBWAOwAmYw4BQ8AJ5NQMBCgUAHgAVUGQAD3hkQjZQACVkLQwCQIkMWDwAcwAaUABXPBk8NTwAPlLQAF5QAG83UAbQAG0AaVAM0BlkTzpOUFCcWODWgF0wyOiCWLw0TFAAflAZhVB+FpH+YfWAbjcAX12vHzIKKlpGZlY2QIBBXIAhCuq-JFmMQOpYWVvQADJQe65Lo9Po3P6dbq9AHlXYebzIfrwsHVGq4fhpDKZbagABG83R8HSWWxBzhPmC8PuVVqaNAGOJoCk+LphMxJMO8NAAFU8LA6HgKT5qoLkGCAD6Ipj3WFSJSDWI8vl4ADCcrYsVg0AYSmQ0Gi8FiJ0oNHoTAwLHYISRuRFj1q9UaUlIiRkiv55zNFrYAAoAJT2xqB0A6+CgcL8N0Czko2kAIljoFJQcd-LYdB16hUmW94V9u0DezcDoaOGpsZwsd2hbcsvloAAkngkpQpPBI6q65rtbr9YbyMaPZdLSK7pLkHa6oGnS7I4PzVc-QHk8HkKHw9zefyRdTUTh+PHE-nl1o8GmM1mc3ni4mi4GQKAACJ0dh4ADkoYIyE4GQR4Bw4H2IA)

It doesn't make a difference for the `TypeA` and `TypeB` shown, since they don't have properties with the same names but different types (like `x` in my description above), but it would if they did — `Common<TypeA | TypeB>` would include `x` as `string | number`, but `SharedProperties<TypeA, TypeB>` leaves it out entirely.

Comment: Super great and detailed answer! Thank you so much!